# How to use MKSnapshotter in Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am currently trying to implement a MKSnapshotter from MapKit. I want to create a snapshot of the location I am finding in a mapview (streetview) using apple maps.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    var options: MKMapSnapshotOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions();
    options.region = self.attractionDetailMap.region;
    options.size = self.attractionDetailMap.frame.size;
    options.scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;

    var fileURL:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "path/to/snapshot.png")!;
    var snapshotter:MKMapSnapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter();
    snapshotter.startWithCompletionHandler { (snapshot:MKMapSnapshot!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            println("error: " + error.localizedDescription);
            return;
        }
        var image:UIImage = snapshot.image;
        var data:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        data.writeToURL(fileURL, atomically: true);

        var pin:MKAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView();
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, true, image.scale);
        image.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0));
        var rect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        for annotation in self.attractionDetailMap.annotations {
            var point:CGPoint = snapshot.pointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        }
    }
```

When I try to make a point (var point:CGPoint = snapshot.pointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);), the error: 'coordinate' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift appears.

Basically, since there aren't many tutorials/guidelines as to how to use the MKSnapshotter in swift, it'd be greatly appreciated if I could see the standard structure of MKSNapshotter in swift. I feel like I was on the right path, but I am stuck at the last line of code, which frankly doesn't even work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast annotations to correct type.

```
for annotation in self.attractionDetailMap.annotations as! [MKAnnotation] {
    let point = snapshot.pointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. How would you then set the image of the streetview and display it on my VC?

Comment: Well, once you have an image, you create a controller that has a view with a image view and you pass your image there and display it in the UIImageView.